# Django Channels no errors in runserver but no page on localhost

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am trying to set up Django channels in an existing Django project, having never used them before. I am following [this](https://www.sourcelair.com/blog/articles/115/django-channels-chat) guide if that helps. You can see below what I get when I runserver, however going to `127.0.0.1:8000` just gives me a message corrupt, page couldn't be loaded error. Because I am new to the concept of channels there is a good chance I have missed something in the setup.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/o2ta_swdev_pie/o2ta_web $ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 11, 2017 - 23:30:18
Django version 1.10.4, using settings 'o2ta_web.settings'
Starting Channels development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Channel layer default (asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2017-05-11 23:30:18,744 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.receive
2017-05-11 23:30:18,748 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.receive
2017-05-11 23:30:18,750 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.receive
2017-05-11 23:30:18,753 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.receive
2017-05-11 23:30:18,796 - INFO - server - Using busy-loop synchronous mode on channel layer
```

I have installed dependencies according to this requirements.txt:

```
# requirements.txt

asgi-redis==1.0.0
channels==0.17.3
daphne==0.15.0
Django==1.10.4
```

And have added consumers.py, routing.py and altered settings.py according to the linked guide.

Does the above output give any indication of where my issue might be? I am not sure where else to look because I am not getting any debug info on my webpage like I would normally expect (yes `DEBUG = true`).

**EDIT:** See my consumers.py and routing.py files below.

```
# consumers.py
def ws_echo(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({
        'text': message.content['text'],
    })

# routing.py
from channels.routing import route

channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.receive', 'main.consumers.ws_echo')
]
```

And I've made these changes in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'main'
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': "asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "o2ta_web.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

Comment: post the error what you are getting while you are accessing a webpage

Comment: Line 1: `Error - http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
Line 2: `The page 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' couldn't be loaded.`
Line 3: `Message Corrupt`

Comment: give the full error page as a pic bro

Comment: And in the console it says `Failed to load resource: Message Corrrupt`. This is literally all there is to see.

Comment: How do your routing and consumers look?

Comment: Edited to include Django code.